Не могу понять как сделать отображение подробности команды?
@bot.tree.command(description="Вся информация о сервере.",)
    async def info(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        """Вся информация о сервере."""
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            'Создатель проекта OVERSLIDE\n' \
            'На сервере будет проводиться многочисленное количество розыгрышей! \n' \
            'Вы также можете помочь нашему серверу!\n' \
            'Вы можете пожертвовать серверу покупая донат или же совершить пожертвование! \n' \
            'Наш сайт: https://love-cs2.ru\n' \
            'VK LOVE-CS2.RU: https://vk.com/lovecs2 \n' \
            'YT OVERSLIDE: https://www.youtube.com/@OVERSLIDEOFF\n' \
            'VK OVERSLIDE: https://vk.com/overslideoff')

Хочу чтобы выводило так

А выводит почему-то так и не могу понять как сделать это еще?

Вместо "-" я хочу написать туда "Вся информация о сервере."

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Ну судя по документации декоратор заполнен верно. Попробуйте перед description указать name команды и убрать ненужную запятую после description.


@bot.tree.command(name="info", description="Вся информация о сервере.", guild=guild_object)
async def info(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(
        'Создатель проекта OVERSLIDE\n' \
        'На сервере будет проводиться многочисленное количество розыгрышей! \n' \
        'Вы также можете помочь нашему серверу!\n' \
        'Вы можете пожертвовать серверу покупая донат или же совершить пожертвование! \n' \
        'Наш сайт: https://love-cs2.ru\n' \
        'VK LOVE-CS2.RU: https://vk.com/lovecs2 \n' \
        'YT OVERSLIDE: https://www.youtube.com/@OVERSLIDEOFF\n' \
        'VK OVERSLIDE: https://vk.com/overslideoff')


У меня выбивает ошибку когда я указываю id сервера в guild

в guild укажите discord.Object(id=...)
